# GCC: include math.h function in bare-metal software on ARM (arm-none-eabi-gcc)

Tags: gcc, arm, stm32h7

I am working on a bare-metal free standing software on a STM32H753. I'm not using neither the libc nor the crt.

Here is the link command line:

`arm-none-eabi-gcc -T"xxx.ld" -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb  -ffreestanding  -nostdlib -nostartfiles --specs=nosys.specs  -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group -Wl,-Map=xxx.map -o xxx.elf  <list of .o>`

Now I need to include math library since I am using `sqrt` function. i thought the link command line would be sufficient but I get a "sqrt undefined" error.

I tried to add the path to the `libm.a`: (also tried without `-Wl`)

`arm-none-eabi-gcc -T"xxx.ld"  -Wl,-L/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb  -ffreestanding  -nostdlib -nostartfiles --specs=nosys.specs  -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group -Wl,-Map=build_uP1/base_gen_uP1.map -o build_uP1/base_gen_uP1.elf  <list of .o>` 
But I still get the same error.

I don't understand what options to choose to link with the correct library

Comment: You are not using libc, you are using sqrt, and you are not providing your own sqrt. You can't have all three.

Comment: sqrt is implemented by libm.a isnt't it ?

Comment: `libm.a: (also tried without -Wl)` Move the link after objects. `gcc <options> <list of .o> -lm`

Comment: Sorry didn't read the question too carefully. libm.a is a part of glibc, but you can (sometimes) use it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this self answer but I think I 've found the solution.

- my first mistake is that the library must be put at the end of the command line. the order of arguments does matter.
- then there are many versions of `libm.a` in the gcc install so I had to pick the right one

The following line is working:

`arm-none-eabi-gcc -T"xxx.ld"  -L/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7+fp/hard/ -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb  -ffreestanding  -nostdlib -nostartfiles --specs=nosys.specs   -Wl,-Map=xxx.map -o xxx.elf <list of .o> -lm -lc`

I've noticed that one symbol and some data from `libc.a` are needed: `__errno`, and `impure_data`

Comment: yep, you need to tell the linker where the library is